# Using StrongParameters permit without removing other keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

In a controller, I'm trying to pass params received from the view to another object (responsible for handling the logic required to complete the action) but I'm struggling with `StrongParameters`.

Is there a way to permit specific values on a key while letting the other params pass through?

For instance, for my `Role` model I'd like to permit `name` and `activity_ids`.

So when the controller gets

```
"role"=>{"name"=>"simple", "activity_ids"=>["", "1", "2"]}, 
"auth_code"=>"123", "button"=>"", "id"=>"simple"}
```

It should pass

```
"role"=>{"name"=>"simple", "activity_ids"=>["", "1", "2"],  permitted: true}, 
"auth_code"=>"123", "button"=>"", "id"=>"simple"}
```

So The role can be created/updated with mass-assignment.

And, at the same should be passed when it receives

```
"role"=>{"name"=>"simple", "activity_ids"=>["", "1", "2"], "injected" => "DELETE FROM roles"}, 
"auth_code"=>"123", "button"=>"", "id"=>"simple"}
```

The only way I can use `permit` is chaining it after `require` but this removes all the other keys.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: you can chain require statements to achieve your need,`params.require(:role).require(:auth_code).require(:id).permit!`

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using two methods,

**Method 1:**

Using `permit_all_parameters`

**`permit_all_parameters` - If it's true, all the parameters will be permitted by default. The default is false.**

`ActionController::Parameters.permit_all_parameters = true`

Eg:

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new
params.permitted? # => false

ActionController::Parameters.permit_all_parameters = true

params = ActionController::Parameters.new
params.permitted? # => true
```

[The reference for permitted parameters](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html)

**Method 2:**

you can chain require statements to achieve your need.

```
params = { "role"=>{"name"=>"simple", "activity_ids"=>["", "1", "2"]}, 
"auth_code"=>"123", "button"=>"", "id"=>"simple" }

params.require(:role).require(:auth_code).require(:id).permit!
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Besides the fact that either method filters out the role parameters. I'm not able to chain `require` statement. When I run your code I get `ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: auth_code`.

Comment: okay, have you tried the first method, `ActionController::Parameters.permit_all_parameters = true`

Comment: try permitting the params directly and check once `params.permit!`